# Configure shardIteratorType to AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER dynamically for in spring cloud stream kinetic binder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

My spring boot application is using  aws kinesis binder which acts as a consumer. I am persisting last sequence number in database, so that at app restart I will read that and processing will start after that sequence number using AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER as a shardIteratorType. I am able to do it by manually updating the config yml with new sequence number. Is there any way I can set this sequence number dynamically.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a `ConsumerEndpointCustomizer<KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter>` bean, catch that `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` for the particular destination and call its `resetCheckpointForShardToSequenceNumber()` whenever you need to change a sequence number at runtime.

Another way is to `stop()` this channel adapter and call its `setStreamInitialSequence()` and then `start()` to apply a new sequence number to all new started consumers internally.

Comment: Could you please elaborate  a bit more how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what is your concern. You provide a `ConsumerEndpointCustomizer<KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter>` `@Bean`. Populate some `AtomicReference<KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter>` with the adapter from that callback. And use that `AtomicReference` from any other service when you need to change the state for the adapter using API I provided in the answer.